# Online service for reading books

Tags: web-apps, ebooks, saas, books, reading

There is a [lot of book-reading software](https://alternativeto.net/software/moon-reader/) but it all works as native apps. Is there something similar that works without installation, just as a web service?

Answer (score 1):

It seems https://play.google.com/books provides a reading experience for the browser, but lacks two things important for me:

- PDF import, which is important for reading studies and scanned books.
- Voice reading is not provided and hard to integrate, even with a [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/natural-reader-text-to-sp/kohfgcgbkjodfcfkcackpagifgbcmimk).